# how to refine functions that have different arity in typescript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

below code doesn't work as i guess

```js
const callbackFunction = (fn: ((oneArgument: number) => void) | (() => void)) => {
  if(fn.length === 1) {
    fn(1);
    return;
  }

  if(fn.length === 0) {
    fn(); //  Error that you must pass one parameter
    return;
  }
}
```

as i know, fn.length return the number of arity. so prior example should have no error.

if i change the code as follow, it works. but i don't know the difference and i want to make a type more specific like error example.

```
const callbackFunction = (fn: (...args: any[]) => void) => {
  if (fn.length === 1) {
    fn(1);
    return;
  }

  if (fn.length === 0) {
    fn(); // No Error
    return;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're using `...args: unknown[]` it basically means that your function can have "any number" of arguments (1, 10, 15 or none). Its not the same as a function that can have only 1 or 0 arguments.

You can refactor the callback function of your first code option to accept 1 optional argument, and the code will work

```
const callbackFunction = (fn: (oneArgument?: number) => void) => {
  if(fn.length === 1) {
    fn(1);
    return;
  }

  if(fn.length === 0) {
    fn();
    return;
  }
}
```

When will happen if you're calling `fn` with 2 arguemnts? it is still a valid statement when number function argument is not explicitly declared (`...args: unknown[]`), while it is not a valid statement when callback function can have 1 or none arguments:

```
const callbackFunction = (fn: (oneArgument?: number) => void) => {
  if(fn.length === 2) {
   fn(1, 2); // Expected 0-1 arguments, but got 2
   return;
  }

  if(fn.length === 1) {
    fn(1);
    return;
  }

  if(fn.length === 0) {
    fn();
    return;
  }
}
```